# Resaltar solo primer registro de una consulta

Tags: php, html, html5, php7

En sí el código ya es funcional, pero me resalta el primer registro de cada página, ya que tiene implementado una paginación de resultados.
Lo que quiero es que solo me muestre el primer registro de otro color aún así sean 2,5 o más páginas.

Acá el código:

```
$rr = $bd->query("SELECT * FROM moduloscurso where idCurso = $idCurso LIMIT $iniciar,$regXpagina"); 


$i=1;

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rr, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
  //Mostrando los cursos!!
  echo $i;
    $bg = ( $i == 1 ) ? "#9eedb4" : "#f7b7b7";//Color de fondo

    $disabled = ( $i == 1 ) ? "" : "disabled";//Activar/Desactivar Boton

    echo '  
        <div class="card" style="width: 200px; background-color:'.$bg.';">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="'.$row['moduloimg'].'">
        <div class="card-body">
        <h6 class="card-title">'.$row['nombreModulo'].'</h6>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush> 
        <li class="list-group-item" id="countdown"></li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <a class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm '.$disabled.'" id="caption" 
            href="empezarCurso.php?idCurso='.$row['idCurso'].'&idModulo='.$row['idModulo'].'">Empezar Módulo
            </a>
        </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
  ';

  $i++;
}
```

En sí lo que quiero es que me resalte el primer registro sin importar la paginación :)

Comment: Pero ¿cuál es el código con el que manejas la paginación o qué variable en tu código representa a la primera página?

Comment: Si la variable que controla las páginas es por ejemplo esta `$regXpagina`, sólo tienes que cambiar el ternario así: `$bg = ( $i == 1 && $regXpagina == 1) ? "#9eedb4" : "#f7b7b7";` O sea, únicamente si `$i` y `$regXpagina` son igual  a `1`, se establecerá el color de fondo `#9eedb4`.

Comment: Gracias Me ayudaste a solucionarlo :)

Answer (score 0):

Sólo tienes que modificar el ternario, haciendo una comprobación sobre el número de página.

Si la variable que controla la paginación es `$regXpagina` el ternario quedaría así:

```
$bg = ( $i == 1 && $regXpagina == 1) ? "#9eedb4" : "#f7b7b7";
```

Aquí el background adquirirá el color `#9eedb4` **únicamente** cuando se trate del primer registro de la primera página.

---

> ### Nota sobre la seguridad
>
> Tu consulta
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM moduloscurso where idCurso = $idCurso LIMIT $iniciar,$regXpagina
> ```
>
> es altamente vulnerable a ataques de *Inyección SQL*. Un usuario mal
> intencionado podría manipular las variables que hay en ella para
> producir estragos en la base de datos o en el sistema. Para
> neutralizar esa posibilidad de ataque deberías usar consultas
> preparadas. Recomiendo que te documentes sobre el asunto cuando sea
> posible.